# show if $X:Z$ and $Y:X$ are algebraic extensions then $Y:Z$ is algebraic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I have found a proof but my proof assumes that the extensions are finite. I am trying to prove it whether or not the extensions are finite. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F/E/K$ is a tower of extensions with $F/E$ and $E/K$ algebraic, and let $u\in F$. We will show that $u$ is algebraic over $K$. To this end, note that $u$ is algebraic over $K$, so $u$ is a root of some polynomial
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\in E[x].$$
In particular, $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ are algebraic over $K$, so $u$ is algebraic over the finite extension $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)/K$. Now, $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u)/K$ is finite (since it is finite over $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$), hence $u$ is algebraic over $K$.

[This proof above is pictured on the cover of the Beachy-Blair Abstract Algebra textbook.]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't follow the conclusion: firstly, how did you conclude $K(a_0,...,a_n,u)/K$ is finite? And how did you follow it up with $u$ being algebraic over $K$.

Comment: $u$ is a root of $f(x)\in K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)[x]$, so $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u)/K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ is finite, and we have $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)/K$ is finite, so $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u)/K$ is finite. @algebraic

Comment: I understand that $K(a_0,...,a_n,u)/K(a_0,...,a_n)$ is finite, and that $K(a_0,...,a_n)/K$ is finite but I don't see how they imply $K(a_0,...,a_n,u)/K$ is finite. Moreover, in order to conclude $u$ is algebraic, don't need $K(u)/K$ to be finite? I assume you're using the Tower Law but I cannot see it.

Comment: No, you just need that $u$ is contained in a finite extension of $K$. Also, the tower law says that if $[A:B]$ is finite and $[B:C]$ is finite, then $[A:C]=[A:B][B:C]$ is finite. Take $A=K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u)$, $B=K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ and $C=K$. @algebraic

Comment: Are you assuming htat $K \subset E \subset F$ here?

Comment: @algebraic Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: Because I am not sure why you are assuming that, I wasn't given it in particular.

Comment: @algebraic If X/Z is an algebraic extension, then $Z\subset X$. You are given that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to understand after the part you say "a_0,...,a_n algebraic over $K$ so... " Now, so we have each one is algebraic over $K$ and I understand that $[K(a_0,...,a_n):K]$ is finite, but I don't follow why that means $u$ is algebraic over $K(a_0,...,a_n)$

Comment: @algebraic We have identified that $u$ is the root of the polynomial $f(x)$ in my post, right? Well, the coefficients of that polynomial all belong to $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ (by construction). SO: $f(x)\in K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)[x]$ satisfies $f(u)=0$. That makes $u$ algebraic over $K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: Nevermind, got it thanks a lot!

Comment: @algebraic This automatically follows from $u$ belonging to a finite extension of $K$ since $[K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u):K]=[K(a_0,\ldots,a_n,u):K(u)][K(u):K]$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $[Y:Z]\le [Y:X][X:Z]$ by noting $y\in Y$ can be represented as

> $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{[Y:X]}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{[X:Z]} c_{ij}z_{ij}j\right)$$

So the size of a spanning set does not exceed the finite number $[Y:X][X:Z]$. Here we choose $c_{ij}$ and $z_{ij}$ such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{[X:Z]}c_{ij}z_{ij}=c'_ix_i$$

and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{[Y:X]}c'_ix_i=y$$

To see each of the others is finite, it's a simple matter of noting that if $y\in Y$ then it is in some finite extension of $X$, eg $X(y)$, which we know is finite because $y$ satisfies a minimal polynomial over $X$. But then if we have

$$y=\sum_{i=1}^{[X(y):X]}c_i'x_i$$

we may choose $z_{ij}\in Z$ satisfying the condition from above because each $x_i$ is algebraic, so $Z(x_1,x_2,\ldots, [X(y):X]$ generate a **finite** extension of $Z$.

So you reduce to the case $X=Z(x_1,\ldots, x_{[X(y):X]}$ and $Y=X(y)$ which are finite extensions and the general case follows.

Comment: But  I don't know $[Y:X][X:Z]$ is finite?

Comment: @algebraic I thought you were having trouble proving $[Y:Z]$ was finite **given** the other two were, but I have edited my solution to explain how to reduce to that case now that I understand your true problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F\subset K$ and $K\subset L$ be algebraic extensions of fields, and pick $\alpha\in L$.

$\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ by assumption, so it satisfies a polynomial equation $\sum_{i=0}^n c_i \alpha^i = 0$ with $c_i\in K$ and $c_n\neq 0$.  In particular, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(c_1, \ldots , c_n)$.

Now consider the extension of fields $F \subset F(c_1, \ldots , c_n) \subset F(\alpha, c_1, \ldots , c_n)$.  Both extensions are finite, so we can apply the result for finite extensions to conclude that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: This is the proof I already gave.